# ClusterManager with InfoWindowAdapter doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using [google's android Map Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) and below is the code I use to try to generate an info window.

```
    /*
     * Set the Google Marker Cluster Manager.
     */
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, mGoogleMap);

    mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
    mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
    mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
    mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager);

    mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mPlaceInfoWindowAdapter);

    mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter infoWindowAdapter = new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "getInfoWIndow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.map_infowindow_layout, null);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "getInfoContents", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return v;
        }
    };

    mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(infoWindowAdapter);

    mClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(infoWindowAdapter);

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MapMarker>()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MapMarker> cluster)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "cluster click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MapMarker>()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterItemClick(MapMarker mapMarker)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "cluster item click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Below is the image of the result when clicking on a marker on the map.
The methods of the InfoWindowAdapter are never called.

[image: Code result]

I've also tried to set the `mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)` but that doesn't work either. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with google's code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by returning `false` from the `onClusterItemClick` method. If set to true, the info window doesn't show.

Comment: Everywhere else it said it needs to be true but your trick of switching it to false also fixed my problem, thanks!